# AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no attribute 'get_color' Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, colors, onclick, shapes, patch

I am trying to make a grid of Rectangles that will change to a specified color when clicked. I have gotten everything to work (including returning the coordinate of the rectangle clicked), however I want to run a conditional statement based on what color the Rectangle is (ex: if the color of the Rectangle being clicked is Gray, then I want it to turn Red and vise versa).
The solution to my problem is being able to get the color of a given Rectangle being clicked. In theory it should be `artist.get_color()`
but it is not working in my situation. Below is my full code.

[image: Example of what I have so far.]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.artist import Artist





fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title("Plot")

floor = 1

def onpick(event):
    artist = event.artist 
    color = "red" 


    # These two conditional statements should work, but they don't. Please Help :). 
    # if artist.get_color() == "gray":
    #     color = "red"
    #
    #
    # elif artist.get_color() == "red":
    #     color = "gray"

    props = {"color": color, "edgecolor": "black", "linewidth": 1}



    Artist.update(artist, props)
    print(artist.get_xy()) 
    plt.draw()

for x in range(0, 10):
    for y in range(0, 10):
        r = plt.Rectangle((x, y), 1, 1, fc = "gray", edgecolor = "black", linewidth = 1, picker = True)
        plt.gca().add_patch(r)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", onpick)
plt.axis("scaled")
# plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You could use `artist.get_facecolor()`, although this will return a tuple of rgba values (normalised to 1)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as you've discovered there is no `get_color` method for the patches. Calling `get_facecolor` (or equivalently, `get_fc`), the return is an RGBA value, which is annoying to work with.

I dug deeper into the class object and found that there is a `_original_facecolor` variable in the class. Now, based on the leading underscore, you're not really meant to use it, but Python doesn't truly have private class variables. So you can use that to get the text form of the *argument you passed*. I italicized that last part because if you had, instead, passed the RGBA values rather than strings for the facecolors, the variable would contain those, i.e. it just saves what you pass to the color setter, it doesn't convert it to some other form. (In the background, `"gray"` is converted to an RGBA value, which is what `get_facecolor` is returning.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.artist import Artist

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title("Plot")

def onpick(event):
    artist = event.artist
    if artist._original_facecolor == "gray":
        color = "red"
    elif artist._original_facecolor == "red":
        color = "gray"
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unhandled {artist._original_facecolor=} option.")

    props = {"color": color, "edgecolor": "black", "linewidth": 1}

    Artist.update(artist, props)
    print(artist.get_xy())
    plt.draw()


for x in range(0, 10):
    for y in range(0, 10):
        r = plt.Rectangle((x, y), 1, 1, fc="gray",
                          edgecolor="black", linewidth=1, picker=True)
        plt.gca().add_patch(r)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", onpick)
plt.axis("scaled")
plt.show()
```